# Java InputData read/write loop with array of filenames

Tags: java, loops, inputstream

Very, very new to java here.  Currently I have code to pull data from a single text file and parse the data in a format that is usable for me (see below.)  Unfortunately, this requires me to have to change the file name for each run.  I would ideally like to automate it by looping through an array of filename strings to collect the data.

Any idea how I can pass the array of filenames and loop it through each name?

```
package weatherfiledata;


import java.io.*;

/**
 *
 *
 */
public class WeatherFileData {
    int month[] = new int[8760];
    int day[] = new int[8760];
    int hour[] = new int[8760];
    int db[] = new int[8760];
    int wb[] = new int[8760];
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count;
        //here i would declare the array of fileNames and start the loop
        //String fileNames[] = {"fileName1","fileName2"...};
        //for(count = 0; count < fileNames.length; count++){


        // TODO code application logic here
        //create an object named "DataInput" of type "WeatherFileData"
        WeatherFileData DataInput = new WeatherFileData();

        DataInput.InputData(DataInput);
        //display data
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<DataInput.month.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(DataInput.wb[i] +",");
        }
        //} end of loop
    }

        void InputData(WeatherFileData DataInput) {
         BufferedReader br = null;
         try {

        String sCurrentLine;
        //this is where I currently have to change the fileName each time;
        //I would like to be able to use the fileName array loop to automate
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileName1.txt"));

        int i=0;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String arr[] = sCurrentLine.split("\t");

            DataInput.month[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
            DataInput.day[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
            DataInput.hour[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
            DataInput.wb[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[3]);
            DataInput.db[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[4]);
            i++;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly problem, there is method ```listFiles()``` in ```File``` class. You could create file object with directory of your files and then list all files within.

Comment: The listFiles() method works great and is a very quick and easy way to integrate this functionality.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by introducing a String variable for the file name:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
```

And pass this variable as an argument to your method:

```
void inputData(WeatherFileData dataInput, String filename) {
```

Then, you can maintain a list of these files, in an array:

```
String[] filenames = new String[5];
filenames[0] = "fileName1.txt";
...
```

And iterate through them with:

```
for(String filename : filenames){
   WeatherFileData dataInput = new WeatherFileData();
   dataInput.inputData(dataInput, filename);
   ... // Do what you want with DataInput
}
```

And as a last comment, notice that you don't need to do that:

```
dataInput.inputData(dataInput, filename);
```

This would be better:

```
dataInput.inputData(filename);
```

But inside the function `inputData()` write this:

```
this.month[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
```

Instead of this:

```
dataInput.month[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
```

(I also removed the capital first letters from your object and method names, which is the convention)

Comment: Thank you so much!  And thank you for correcting my bad coding conventions!

Answer (score 0):

I just tweaked your code little bit. Hope it works

```
package weatherfiledata;
import java.io.*;

/**
 *
 *
 */
public class WeatherFileData {
    int month[] = new int[8760];
    int day[] = new int[8760];
    int hour[] = new int[8760];
    int db[] = new int[8760];
    int wb[] = new int[8760];
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {




        //create an object named "DataInput" of type "WeatherFileData"
        WeatherFileData dataInput = new WeatherFileData();

     String fileNames[] = {"fileName1","fileName2"...};
        for(int count = 0; count < fileNames.length; count++){
        dataInput.inputData(fileNames[count],count);

    }


        //display data
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<dataInput.month.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(dataInput.wb[i] +",");
        }
        //} end of loop
    }

        void inputData(String fileName, int currentIndex) {
         BufferedReader br = null;
         try {

        String sCurrentLine;
        //this is where I currently have to change the fileName each time;
        //I would like to be able to use the fileName array loop to automate
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        int i=0;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String arr[] = sCurrentLine.split("\t");

            this.month[currentIndex] = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
            this.day[currentIndex] = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
            this.hour[currentIndex] = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
            this.wb[currentIndex] = Integer.parseInt(arr[3]);
            this.db[currentIndex] = Integer.parseInt(arr[4]);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: also try avoiding intializing arrays by harcoding 8760. You can use ArrayList instead

Comment: Thank you for the help and for the coding convention tips!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you something more flexible(java 7):

```
package weatherfiledata;
import java.io.*;

public class WeatherFileData {
    int month[] = new int[8760];
    int day[] = new int[8760];
    int hour[] = new int[8760];
    int db[] = new int[8760];
    int wb[] = new int[8760];

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO code application logic here
        //create an object named "DataInput" of type "WeatherFileData"
        WeatherFileData DataInput = new WeatherFileData();

        DataInput.InputData(DataInput, args[0]/*Path to files*/);
        //display data
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < DataInput.month.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(DataInput.wb[i] + ",");
        }
    }

    void InputData(WeatherFileData DataInput, String path) {
        final File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

                    String sCurrentLine;
                    int i = 0;
                    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        String arr[] = sCurrentLine.split("\t");

                        DataInput.month[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
                        DataInput.day[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
                        DataInput.hour[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
                        DataInput.wb[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[3]);
                        DataInput.db[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[4]);
                        i++;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And of course, please read about java naming convention. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html